# Problems with double pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to create a new Node object with the pointer variable *temp in line 15 below. I'm still pretty new to c++ and how double pointers work, especially when used in combination with &. Thanks for any help.

```
void bst::insert(int n) {
    Node **temp;
    Node *r, *parent;
    // Tree is empty
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new Node;
        root->parent = NULL;
        root->value = n;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        root->isBlack = true;
    } else {
        r = root;
        // Create a node with the given value, n
        (*temp) = new Node;
        (*temp)->value = n;
        (*temp)->left = NULL;
        (*temp)->right = NULL;
        (*temp)->isBlack = false;
```

Comment: Why do you need a double pointer?

Comment: i'm using double pointers as parameters for my rotate and balance methods; this is a red-black binary search tree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `temp` is not initialized. Therefore, trying to dereference `temp` will fail, as there is no value to dereference. If you really need a pointer to a pointer, you could just declare the single pointer and use the `&` operator to get the double pointer.

Comment: To clarify @jma127's answer, you've only initialized `*temp`, but have not initialized `temp`.

Answer (score 2):

`temp` doesn't point to anything valid, so when you do

```
(*temp) = new Node;
(*temp)->value = n;
(*temp)->left = NULL;
(*temp)->right = NULL;
(*temp)->isBlack = false;
```

in the `else` branch of your `if`-statement, you're going to invoke undefined behavior when you dereference the `temp` pointer variable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't want to use a double pointer here (or a pointer-to-a-pointer as I prefer to call them).  `temp` holds an address of a pointer which is never initialised.  So when you try to create a `new Node` you are attempting to create it at whatever random data `temp` has been initialised with.

You could just use a normal pointer, then if you need to make it a pointer-to-pointer later just use `&temp`:

```
Node * temp;

// <snip>

temp = new Node;
Node->value = n;
//  etc.

SomeFunc( &temp );  //  temp will be passed as a pointer-to-pointer (Node**).
```

Alternatively if you insist that temp remains a pointer-to-pointer you could use:

```
Node * temp2 = new Node;  // Creates a new Node and assigns the address to temp2
temp = &temp2;            // Assigns the address of the pointer to the Node (temp2) to temp.

//  Now do stuff.
```

Remember you'll need to delete it like this:

```
delete( *temp );
```